# Telosys does not generate column definition (i.e. for CHAR-columns)

Tags: telosys

When using Telosys to generate entities with the java7-persistence-commons-jpa-T300 templates the column annotation never includes columnDefinition when generating the @Column annotation in JpaRecord-classes. That forces database schemageneration with hbm2ddl always to generate VARCHAR columns.
But when the origin database column is an CHAR-column the generated record-class should also generate columnDefinition... i.e.: @Column(**columnDefinition = "CHAR(xx)"**, name = "VVT_NR", nullable = false, length = 20)

Is there a way to force telosys to generate the columnDefinition (with correct length for xx of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JPA function "$jpa.**fieldAnnotations**()”
used in the mentioned template is a shortcut to generate the "classical" JPA annotations for a given field and indeed it doesn’t generated all the “@Column” optional elements (for example “table”, “insertable”, “updatable” and  “columnDefinition” are not generated)

In version 3 there's no way to force the generator to produce the "columnDefinition".

But if you really want to generate the “columnDefinition” you can create a specific function or a specific macro.

To create a **Velocity macro** see :

- http://www.telosys.org/templates-doc/velocity/macro.html
- [http://people.apache.org/~henning/docbook/html/ch07.html](http://people.apache.org/%7Ehenning/docbook/html/ch07.html)

To create a **specific function** see this other question :

- [Is it possible in a Telosys template to call a function created specifically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467530/is-it-possible-in-a-telosys-template-to-call-a-function-created-specifically)

For a specific function you can reuse the "$jpa" class source code :

- https://github.com/telosys-tools-bricks/telosys-tools-generator/blob/master/src/main/java/org/telosys/tools/generator/context/Jpa.java