# Can telosys generation invoke external program prior to writing to target location and based on the return value continue or cancel writing to target

Tags: code-generation, dsl, telosys

I want to generate c# asp.net core razor pages with many projects: Application, Domain, Infrastructure, Core etc.

I would like to know if Telosys is extensible to allow a custom console program to be called with arguments: ,  so this program can do some code merges in order to preserve possible additions/changes to the code a developer did since the previous code generation?

C# can have some directives called #region to partition the code and these will be "regenerate only regions" and outside these regions the developer can put his own code. We need to preserver his code.
C# Partial classes and methods can also help.

I want to have capability to **merge newly re-generated code** (e.g. entity class - I can add some properties or change some property name, type, annotations, tags etc.) **into previously generated entity class**. This could be done by creating **#region .... #endregion** where the code can be regenerated into and **all the code that is outside these regions should be preserved**. See: efg.loresoft.com/en/latest/regeneration So I would like to know if there would be a way to temporarily generate files in a TMPGEN folder and allow some "merge program to run" that will mege new code with previously generated code (with some code added by the developer) previously determining if merge is needed (compare hashes)

This is the code from EntityFrameworkCore.Generator tool that merges existing regions [https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFrameworkCore.Generator..EntityFrameworkCore.Generator.Core/Templates/CodeTemplateBase.cs](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFrameworkCore.Generator/blob/2a0a52214853c343c73c08bafd36c27071c6e0bc/src/EntityFrameworkCore.Generator.Core/Templates/CodeTemplateBase.cs) has the protected virtual method:

void **MergeOutput**(string **fullPath**, string **outputContent**) show that fullPath is an existing file and outputContent is the result of parsing the template (new content). RegionParser uses these namespaces: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp; and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
so I need to user c# console application to user this preserver region code.

Thanks,
Rad

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Telosys is extensible by using specific Java classes loaded in the template context with **$loader**

See : [Is it possible in a Telosys template to call a function created specifically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467530/is-it-possible-in-a-telosys-template-to-call-a-function-created-specifically/)

So, you just have to create a Java class to launch any Shell command

For example, see : [How to get java getRuntime().exec() to run a command-line program with arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467307/how-to-get-java-getruntime-exec-to-run-a-command-line-program-with-arguments)